# Storing methods and calling them by random?

Tags: java

I'm looking to create a lot of methods, and I want the user to be given one by random. What might be an efficient way to accomplish this? Could I use an Enum? Switch statement?

Here's a small example.

```
private void giveAssignment() {
    Random randomTask = new Random();
    int assignments = 3;
    assignments = randomTask.nextInt(assignments);
    switch(assignments) {
    case 0:
        doSomething();
        break;
    case 1:
        doSomethingElse();
        break;
    case 2:
        doAnotherThing();
        break;
    }
}

private void doSomething() {
    //
}

private void doSomethingElse() {
    //
}

private void doAnotherThing() {
    //
}
```

Comment: I think using `switch` is absolutely ok for this purpose, don't see any obstacles for this.

Answer (score 5):

You could store them in a list (or array) of `Runnable`s, which you can easily populate using method references:

```
private void giveAssignment() {

    List<Runnable> methods = Arrays.asList(
        this::doSomething,
        this::doSomethingElse,
        this::doAnotherThing);

    int assignments = randomTask.nextInt(methods.size());
    methods.get(assignments).run();
}
```

This seems more scalable than using a switch: it is much easier to add a new method to the list of options. You don't even necessarily need to actually define a method;

```
List<Runnable> methods = Arrays.asList(
    this::doSomething,
    this::doSomethingElse,
    this::doAnotherThing,
    () -> { /* some other code to execute here */ }
);
```

Comment: Just what I had in mind regarding a Lamda solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

A switch is probably fine - altough extending additional "ways that something could happen" would have you extending that same code on top of creating the new behaviour.

Another way to approach this would be to define a common interface for the thing to be done:

```
public interface Something {
  public void nowMakeItHappen();
}
```

Then go implementing your different behaviours implementing this interface:

```
public class OneThing  implements Something {
  public void nowMakeItHappen() {
    //do it here
  }
}
public class SecondThing  implements Something {
  public void nowMakeItHappen() {
    //do it here
  }
}
```

Then in your main class you keep a list of possible Things to do:

```
List<Something> waysToDoThings = new ArrayList<Something>();
waysToDoThings.add(new OneThing());
waysToDoThings.add(new SecondThing());
```

and then pick one of the things randomly:

```
assignments = randomTask.nextInt(waysToDoThings.size());
waysToDoThings.get(assignments).nowMakeItHappen();
```

Of cause you'll now have to add the new subclasses into the list - but I feel this would be less effort compared to the `switch`.

Ultimately you might even want to consider creating an Annotation for classes that fit your pattern and fetch all classes annotated and implementing the interface to be added into your list...

It's probably also possible to do something cool with Lambdas here...